# Query Outlook Calendar for Locations on Events

Tags: api, outlook, office365api, outlook-restapi, outlook-calendar

Does anyone know if there is a way to retrieve locations on calendar events? It looks like the api currently only allows users to see title and start/end date on the event. I would like to be able to see the conference room location. Thanks!

[Outlook Calendar REST API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office365/api/calendar-rest-operations#CalendarResource)

Answer (score 1):

When you query for events, you will always get the location back as well as the organizer, attendees, ...

Try the following api, for example:

```
https://outlook.office365.com/api/v2.0/me/calendarview?startDateTime=2017-07-01T00:00:00Z&endDateTime=2017-07-31T23:59:59Z&$top=10
```

or if you know the event ID, then you can use the following api:

```
https://outlook.office365.com/api/v2.0/me/events/[eventID]
```